# How do I easily strip just a comma from an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

I have a UILabel with the following text:

```
Medium, Black
```

What I intended to do was grab the words in the string and insert each into a mutable array so I could use each title later on to identify something.

**Here's how I done this:**

```
 NSMutableArray *chosenOptions = [[[[cell tapToEditLabel] text] componentsSeparatedByString: @" "] mutableCopy];

    NSString *size = [chosenOptions objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *colour = [chosenOptions objectAtIndex:1];
```

I've logged these two NSString and size is returning "Medium," and colour is correctly returning "Black".

**My comparison result is always false because of the comma:**

```
itemExists = [[item colour] isEqualToString:colour] && [[item size] isEqualToString:size] ? YES : NO;
```

That comma causes itemExists to always equal NO.

Would appreciate a simple solution in code please.

The solution needs to only strip commas and not other characters. When dealing with clothing sizes for females I use sizes in a string like this: "[8 UK]" so remove non-alphanumeric characters would remove these. So I really need a solution to deal with just the commas.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than splitting on spaces, you could split on spaces or commas, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *chosenOptions = [[[[cell tapToEditLabel] text] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,"]] mutableCopy];
[chosenOptions removeObject:@""];
```

This would eliminate commas from the `size` and `colour` strings.

Comment: Medium is returned without the comma but the colour is removed completely.

Comment: I think I've checked the wrong thing on NSLog. Let me try again and I will report back.

Comment: @LondonGuy Please see the edit. When you use this method, you get back `@[ @"Medium", @"", @"Black"]`. The documentation says this is what is supposed to happen. I added `removeObject:@""` call to remove the empty string.

Comment: Getting an error. "initializing nsmutablearray *_strong with an expression of incompatible type void"

Answer (score 2):

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

easy squeezy lemon peesey

Comment: How can the words be split if you remove the commas?

Comment: I thought he was asking how to remove commas from a string, not split them

Comment: The OP is doing it wrong. He has a list of comma separated words. This means they need to be split on the commas, not the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString * myString = @"Medium, Black";

NSString * newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@", " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@xx",newString);
```

Comment: This will leave the second string with a leading space. Try `@", "`.

Comment: that will elimate comma and space, effectively merging the words

Comment: Oops - I completely misread the answer. My original comment was based on passing `@", "` to the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method.