# How do I easily separate a set of strings stored in a larger NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

I had a UILabel with the following text:

```
Medium, Black
```

What I intended to do was grab the words in the string and insert each into a mutable array so I could use each title later on to identify something.

**With the help of Stackoverflow I done it like this:**

```
NSMutableArray *chosenOptions = [[[[cell tapToEditLabel] text] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,"]] mutableCopy];
[chosenOptions removeObject:@""];
```

**Now I can access this objects and they return the correct strings:**

```
NSString *size = [chosenOptions objectAtIndex:0]; //Medium
NSString *colour = [chosenOptions objectAtIndex:1]; //Black
```

This is fine. But the problem starts when dealing with female sizes instead of males which are displayed like this:

```
[8 UK], [10 UK], [12 UK], [14 UK]
```

Let us say I now have a UILabel with the following text:

```
[8 UK], Black
```

**Using the same code above my NSLog here:**

```
NSLog(@"size label-> %@", size); 
NSLog(@"colour label-> %@", colour);
```

**Reads back:**

```
size label-> [8

colour label-> UK]
```

Would appreciate a simple solution in code please.

The code that does the stripping doesn't take into account the way my female sizes are set in a string. I need a solution that will work with both male and female size string styles.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `componentsSeparatedByString:@", "`.

```
NSArray *chosenOptions = [[[cell tapToEditLabel] text] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Comment: Originall done this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717057/how-do-i-easily-strip-just-a-comma-from-an-nsstring and it caused another issue with one of the strings being returned with a comma at the end

Comment: If you want easy then you need clean consistent data. If your data doesn't always use the same separator or some have extra characters then you no longer have easy. You could separate on just `@","` (no space) and then trim spaces from each value as well as ignore empty values.

Comment: BTW - your question was about a specific format. If you really have other formats giving you issues, then update your question with that data so people can help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean rmaddy. Everything I've provided in this question is directly related to my issue.

Comment: You said you had strings with trailing commas. The data in this question has no trailing commas. My answer assumes the data in this question - data with elements separated by a comma and space.

Comment: "Medium, Black" had a trailing comma and it was solved using the first piece of code but that same code caused my "[8 UK], Black" string to mess things up for me.

Comment: Correct thanks. Had to add an if statement for when there's no colour option and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this that works with trailing commas with or without whitespace.

```
NSString *tag = @"Medium, Black";
NSMutableArray *options = [[tag componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
NSString *size = [[options objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString *color = [[options objectAtIndex:1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%@:%@", size, color);
```

We first split by just `,` and then remove all extra whitespace.

Here is some sample data:

```
NSArray *tags = @[@"[8 UK], Black", @"Medium, Black", @"Large, Red, ", @"Small, Black,"];
for (NSString *tag in tags) {
    NSMutableArray *options = [[tag componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
    NSString *size = [[options objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *color = [[options objectAtIndex:1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"%@:%@", size, color);
}
```